# Repetitive entries in SQL JOIN query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, data-modeling

I have three tables **posts**, **comments**, and **users**. posts table includes two types of posts, *question* and *answer*. Comments are made on questions and answers. My purpose is to get a single question with comments on it, answers on it and comments on that answers. Also I need username from the users table as author on each question, answer and comment I fetch. I am using Postgres 9.5, and making use of `json_agg()` function.

While example output I need should be something similar to the first following, I get repeated entries.

What is the thing I am missing here? Correct group by clauses may be. Or the subquery to gather the answers with their comments is not the way to do it. When I comment out the left join from posts on the comments table I get desired results without comments on questions. Also when I cancel the left join containing the subquery I get non-repetative results as I expect, and again that is not complete dataset I desire. These are things I have collected so far to solve my issue.

What I need:

```
[
  {
    "post_id": "10",
    "created_at": "2016-05-10T00:16:54.469Z",
    "post_type": "question",
    "post_title": "qwerty",
    "post_text": "asdasd asda sdasd",
    "post_author_id": 1,
    "author": "isikfsc",
    "parent_post_id": null,
    "is_accepted": null,
    "acceptor_id": null,
    "answers": [
      {
        "post_id": 17,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:58:56.350229",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "222asda dasdad asdada",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "author": "isikfsc",
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:56:30.220128",
            "text": "qweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "author": "isikfsc",
            "parent_post_id": 17
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T11:00:00.182991",
            "text": "sasasd",
            "author_id": 1,
            "author": "isikfsc",
            "parent_post_id": 17
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:19:19.005556",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "asdasdasdasd",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "author": "isikfsc",
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:34.671008",
            "text": "qeqweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "author": "isikfsc",
            "parent_post_id": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "comments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:56:30.220128",
          "text": "qweqwe",
          "author_id": 1,
          "author": "isikfsc",
          "parent_post_id": 10
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "created_at": "2016-05-10T11:00:00.182991",
          "text": "sasasd",
          "author_id": 1,
          "author": "isikfsc",
          "parent_post_id": 10
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

My query is:

```
SELECT
    q.*,
    json_agg(ac.*) AS answers,
    json_agg(c.*) AS comments --comments on posts of post_id questions
FROM posts q

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            a.*,
            json_agg(c.*) AS comments -- comments on posts of post_id answers
        FROM posts a
        LEFT JOIN comments c
        ON a.post_id = c.parent_post_id

        GROUP BY a.post_id
    ) ac
ON q.post_id = ac.parent_post_id

LEFT JOIN comments c
ON q.post_id = c.parent_post_id

WHERE q.post_id = 10
GROUP BY q.post_id
```

What I get:

```
[
  {
    "post_id": "10",
    "created_at": "2016-05-10T00:16:54.469Z",
    "post_type": "question",
    "post_title": "qwerty",
    "post_text": "asdasd asda sdasd",
    "post_author_id": 1,
    "parent_post_id": null,
    "is_accepted": null,
    "acceptor_id": null,
    "answers": [
      {
        "post_id": 17,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:58:56.350229",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "222asda dasdad asdada",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:56:30.220128",
            "text": "qweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T11:00:00.182991",
            "text": "sasasd",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 17,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:58:56.350229",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "222asda dasdad asdada",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:56:30.220128",
            "text": "qweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T11:00:00.182991",
            "text": "sasasd",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 17,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:58:56.350229",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "222asda dasdad asdada",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:56:30.220128",
            "text": "qweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T11:00:00.182991",
            "text": "sasasd",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 17,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:58:56.350229",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "222asda dasdad asdada",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:56:30.220128",
            "text": "qweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T11:00:00.182991",
            "text": "sasasd",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 17
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:19:19.005556",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "asdasdasdasd",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:34.671008",
            "text": "qeqweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:19:19.005556",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "asdasdasdasd",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:34.671008",
            "text": "qeqweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:19:19.005556",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "asdasdasdasd",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:34.671008",
            "text": "qeqweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "post_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T04:19:19.005556",
        "post_type": "answer",
        "post_title": null,
        "post_text": "asdasdasdasd",
        "post_author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10,
        "is_accepted": null,
        "acceptor_id": null,
        "comments": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:34.671008",
            "text": "qeqweqwe",
            "author_id": 1,
            "parent_post_id": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:28.200327",
        "text": "asadasdad",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:25:23.381177",
        "text": "werwer",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:28.200327",
        "text": "asadasdad",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:25:23.381177",
        "text": "werwer",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:28.200327",
        "text": "asadasdad",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:25:23.381177",
        "text": "werwer",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T05:25:28.200327",
        "text": "asadasdad",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-05-10T10:25:23.381177",
        "text": "werwer",
        "author_id": 1,
        "parent_post_id": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping happens once all of the parties have been joined, so aggregates will depend on the resulting cardinality. Joining posts with answers AND comments causes a full join between them, duplicating all values. They need to be separated and performed individually, one way you can do it is the following:

```
SELECT
    q.*,
    (SELECT json_agg(ac.*)
     FROM (
       SELECT a.*, json_agg(c.*) AS comments
       FROM posts a
       LEFT JOIN comments c ON (a.post_id = c.parent_post_id)
       WHERE a.parent_post_id = q.post_id
       GROUP BY a.post_id
       ) ac
    ) AS answers,
    json_agg(c.*) AS comments --comments on posts of post_id questions
FROM posts q
LEFT JOIN comments c ON (q.post_id = c.parent_post_id)
WHERE q.post_id = 10
GROUP BY q.post_id;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT q.*, qa.answers, qc.comments
FROM posts q
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ac.parent_post_id, json_agg(ac.*) AS answers
  FROM (
    SELECT ac.*, json_agg(c.*) AS comments
    FROM posts ac
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON (c.parent_post_id = ac.post_id)
    GROUP BY ac.post_id
    ) ac
  GROUP BY ac.parent_post_id
  ) qa ON (qa.parent_post_id = q.post_id)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT c.parent_post_id, json_agg(c.*) AS comments
  FROM comments c
  GROUP BY c.parent_post_id
  ) qc ON (qc.parent_post_id = q.post_id)
WHERE q.post_id = 10;
```

Comment: I get two error messages from these queries at my terminal. First one is for the former: `[error: syntax error at or near "."]`and the second one for the latter: `[error: syntax error at or near "FROM"]`. I could not find why? I keep checking to figure out.

Comment: By `LEFT JOIN comments c (q.post_id = c.parent_post_id)` did you mean `LEFT JOIN comments c ON q.post_id = c.parent_post_id`

Comment: @Işık Yes, fixed both bugs now

Comment: The first one is ok now, no errors. The second one at the last left join lacks a ON I think. When I add it says at Line 9 table q cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: It still says the same thing.
After all the first one also does not produce the result I need. It does not put the answers inside the answers, but it put the post itself with the comments on this post inside the answers key.

Comment: I have made the edit that give it final juice. Can you review? And the second alternative is still problem. But you can remove it if you do not think it has any significant performance or any other advantages to the first one. Alternatively we can fix it. Then I will accept the answer. What to do?

Comment: @Işık Apologies for having posted such buggy code (it is easiers when users provide sample data in their question). Thanks for your correction, that would have fixed it. I applied it to the second case (which had the same problem), and added fields to the main SELECT (which I had left blank!). Hopefully this time they'll both work, for you to compare which one performs better with your data.

Comment: My apologies for lack of sample data. The second one still not working and have the same q cannot be referenced here problem.

Comment: @Işık I rewrote the second query entirely, I rushed it and it was really bad! It may still have a bug, but now it makes sense.

Comment: Ok. It still have the same kind of error, this time for ac. But we can remove it and accept the answer. Or we can put a line on it telling that was for general approach.